# Node.js higher-order function

Tags: node.js, https, higher-order-functions

I am trying to send a http request when an event is entering, but the console outputs in the higher-order function are not working.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const req = https.get('https://test.com', (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    
      let data = "";
  
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        data += d;
      });
      
      res.on('end', () => {
        let url = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(url);
      });
  
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
    
    return 0;
};
```

Happy for every help i can get!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code snippet you provided,

```js
const https = require('https');
    const func = async () => {
    
        const req = https.get('https://test.com', (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    
            let data = "";
    
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                data += d;
            });
    
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log({data})
                let url = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(url);
            });
    
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });
    
        return 0;
};
    
func();
```

- `console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);`
  is the correct way to retrieve `statusCode` from `res`.
- `let url = JSON.parse(data);`
  `data` is not json, it cannot be parsed

`res` is an `instanceOf` `IncomingMessage`

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/all.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage
- Have a look at the documentation to understand what is passed on the events emitted

Run the updated code so that you can see what is logged to `stdOut`